# How to Solve Similar No Of Parameter Combinations in Urls using Mod Rewrite Rule in Htaccess PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have Four Urls which need to be optimized using ht-access PHP.

All Parameter values stored in DB.

**First url** : has TWO Parameters and values in the un-optimized url.

- 1st - (scode)Parameter used for Alphabets - Ex: Only state codes: DL or AP
- 2nd - (disturl)Parameter used for Alphabets,Letters & Symbols  - Ex: District Name: "east-godavarai" District in Andhra Pradesh.

First Url Working - Check Code.

**Second Url**: has THREE Parameters and values in the un-optimized url.

- 1st - (scode)Parameter only Alphabets - Ex: AP
- 2nd - (disturl)Parameter only Alphabets & Hypens   Ex: east-godavari
- 3rd - (talukurl) Parameter only Alphabets & Hypens Ex: vizag-west

Second Url also working - Check code

**Third Url**: has TWO Parameters and values in the un-optimized url.

- 1st - (scode)Parameter only Alphabets - Ex: AP
- 2nd - (pourl)Parameter only Alphabets, Numbers & Hypens   Ex: Narasaraopeta-712345

Url - Not Working Error - Showing The second Url page - No data is getting displayed.

**Fourth Url**: has TWO Parameters and values in the un-optimized url.

- 1st - (scode)Parameter only Alphabets - Ex: AP
- 2nd - (pincode)Parameter only Numbers - Ex: 712345

Url - Not Working Error - Showing The second Url page - No data is getting displayed.

I tried checking each rule separately, 1st rule & 2nd rule worked. When I tried removing 1st & 2nd urls then third url is working and 4th rule is showing 3rd rule url page.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)\.php$ dist.php?scode=$1&disturl=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)\.php$ pos.php?scode=$1&disturl=$2&talukurl=$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+).php loc.php?scode=$1&pourl=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9]+)\.php$ pincode.php?scode=$1&pincode=$2 [NC]
```

**I am expecting the output something like Optimized Urls..**

First Rule:
Main URL: https://www.example.com/dist.php?scode=ap&disturl=krishna

Optimized URL:  https://www.example.com/ap/krishna.php

Second Rule:
Main URL: https://www.example.com/pos.php?scode=ap&disturl=krishna&talukurl=east-godavari

Optimized URL:  https://www.example.com/ap/krishna/east-godavari.php

Third Rule:
Main URL: https://www.example.com/loc.php?scode=ap&pourl=krishnalanka-342563

Optimized URL:  https://www.example.com/ap/krishnalanka-342563.php

Fourth Rule:
Main URL: https://www.example.com/pincode.php?scode=ap&pincode=342563

Optimized URL:  https://www.example.com/ap/342563.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with data alone unless you first look up each possible combination of parameters in your database *before* passing it to the relevant script, this would also miss non-unique parameter combinations. Try instead to prefix each URL type with another slug, e.g. `https://www.example.com/pos/ap/krishna/east-godavari`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your Reply,  I have added a extra word before the scode (ap) As you said, but no luck.... 2nd Rewrite url is working for me... 3rd and 4th rule are not working.  3rd rule has scode & pourl as parameters. - pourl has unique value..

Comment: Did you update your rules to include the prefix? E.g. `RewriteRule ^dist/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)$ dist.php?scode=$1&disturl=$2 [NC,QSA,END]` Also you seem to be missing flags like `END` or `L,DPI`.

Comment: Hi, I tried them but not working... So i have made some change in 3rd rule by adding a extra folder and it worked.. Confused with 4th rule... Looking for help...  RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)\.php$ dist.php?scode=$1&disturl=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)\.php$ pos.php?scode=$1&disturl=$2&talukurl=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+)/([-|0-9|a-z|A-Z]+).php loc.php?fm=$1&disturl=$2&talukurl=$3&pourl=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([-|0-9]+)\.php$ pincode.php?sm=$1&pincode=$2 [NC]

Comment: You're missing the point, you haven't prefixed any of your rules to make them unique. You did not add the flags, either; you need `END` (or if your Apache is old, both `L` and `DPI`). You don't need `.php` in the pretty URL and don't put pipes inside square brackets unless you want to match a literal pipe character in your URL. https://regex101.com/r/lFBsGV/1